# Unexpected behaviour of variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Am I just having a senior moment... this seems counterintuitive to me.

Consider the following:

DDLs

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('a'),('b'),('c');
```

Query

```
SELECT a.id a_id
     , a.rank a_rank
     , b.id b_id
     , b.rank b_rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id 
            , @i := @i+1 rank
         FROM my_table 
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id 
            , @i := @i+1 rank
         FROM my_table 
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
     ) b;
```

Result

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| a_id | a_rank | b_id | b_rank |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| a    |      1 | a    |      4 |
| b    |      2 | a    |      4 |
| c    |      3 | a    |      4 |
| a    |      1 | b    |      5 |
| b    |      2 | b    |      5 |
| c    |      3 | b    |      5 |
| a    |      1 | c    |      6 |
| b    |      2 | c    |      6 |
| c    |      3 | c    |      6 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Expected result

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| a_id | a_rank | b_id | b_rank |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| a    |      1 | a    |      1 |
| b    |      2 | a    |      1 |
| c    |      3 | a    |      1 |
| a    |      1 | b    |      2 |
| b    |      2 | b    |      2 |
| c    |      3 | b    |      2 |
| a    |      1 | c    |      3 |
| b    |      2 | c    |      3 |
| c    |      3 | c    |      3 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Fiddle of same http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15f389/3

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you can't use the same variable name twice in a query

Comment: I can see that using a different variable name each time fixes the problem, but surely the subqueries should be evaluated first, on their own merits!!

Comment: MySQL variables are connection-global. Sad but true.

Comment: Read & write of the same variable in the same select statement in MySQL is undefined. See the manual. People at Percona have shown by examining implementation code that some version(s) allow certain predictable breaking of that rule via certain use of case statements. But I don't have a link.

Comment: Finally, someone has something constructive to say on the matter. Still, better late than never!

Comment: I suggest next time @Strawberry that you ask your question with a bit more thought, as just posting some queries wont help anyone give accurate feedback.

Comment: @BenSouthall Why are you excavating posts from  5 years ago? Are you going for the archaeology badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use different variables in the two sides of the query:

```
SELECT a.id a_id
     , a.rank a_rank
     , b.id b_id
     , b.rank b_rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id 
            , @i := @i+1 rank
         FROM my_table 
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id 
            , @i1 := @i1+1 rank
         FROM my_table 
            , (SELECT @i1:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
     ) b;
```

What is happening is that the two subqueries that initialize the value of `@i` are being run first, then the rest of the query.  There is no guarantee on when subqueries are run, so this is permitted.

Comment: I find it odd that I never noticed this before - but I just tried running same code in older version. Same result, so it must always have been this way :-$